# AngularJS - issue when embedding Youtube video with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

So I basically copied and pasted the code from this

http://plnkr.co/edit/0N728e9SAtXg3uBvuXKF?p=preview

To embed a youtube video.

It all works well, but now I'm trying to embed a youtube video where the "youtube video ID" is retrieved via service.

So in my controller, I do something like

```
  APIService.getVideo($stateParams.videoId).then(function(video) {
    $scope.code = video.youtube_video_id;
  });
```

And in my template, I have

```
<div my-youtube code="code"></div>
```

But this is not working.

Basically, in the directive,

```
app.directive('myYoutube', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: { code:'=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div style="height:400px;"><iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" width="100%" height="100%" src="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.$watch('code', function (newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
          scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newVal);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

where there is `src="{{url}}"` I get `"localhost/myapp/{{url}}" does not exist.`

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the plnkr you linked to include getting the code from a service. http://plnkr.co/edit/BggETGi7zAWL5bdHd0hO?p=preview

Here is my service, which basically mocks a server call for a code

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($q) {
  return {
    getCode: function() {
      var def = $q.defer();
      setTimeout(function() {
        def.resolve('oHg5SJYRHA0');
      }, 2000);
      return def.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!
Otherwise it would be helpful to get a broken plnkr to work off of

Comment: hm, so what's actually going on here? I have to delay the returning of the data so that it loads properly? seems a very 'hacky'...... no?

Comment: the timeout is just there to simulate a server call.